# Is the space $\mathbb{PR}^3$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{PR}^2\times S^1$?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, topological-groups, fiber-bundles, orthogonal-matrices

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Topology) Wiki article it is described how the $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to the projective space $\mathbb{RP}^3$. I would suggest another way which I hope it works.

On $S^2$ one may take any direction (not vector) as an axis of rotation, and for each such axis we have the rotation about it as an $S^1$. Since the set of all directions is topologised as the projective plane $\mathbb{PR}^2$, so at least it must be true that $SO(3)$ is some fiber bundle $(E,\pi,\mathbb{PR}^2)$ of $S^1$ over $\mathbb{PR}^2$. But is it possible to assume that $SO(3) \overset{?}{\cong} \mathbb{PR}^2 \times S^1$ (a trivial bundle) ? and hence, is the space $\mathbb{PR}^3$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{PR}^2\times S^1$ ?

Comment: No. Being a Z/2-quotient of S^3, the fundamental group of the real projective solid equals Z/2. But the product of the real projective plane and a circle has fundamental group isomorphic to Z/2 x Z.

Comment: How much algebraic topology do you know? Typically, one proves that two spaces are not homeomorphic by finding some invariants coming from algebraic topology that distinguish the two spaces. If you do not know **any** such invariants, then it's pretty much  hopeless. As for the two spaces, the easiest thing to observe is that one is orientable ($RP^3$) and the other is not. Or use the fundamental group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Actually nothing. I'm not even beginner in that. It was only an idea of how to find the topology of $SO(3)$. I know it might be wrong but I didn't think I could find the answer alone so I posted it here. Also to see how kowledge I need for this kind of tasks

Comment: Then my suggestion is to learn some topology while you are continuing your physics studies. This will be a good time investment since you will find more and more topological questions as you are learning physics.

Comment: Actually I know some Topolog, smooth manifold and differential geometry, plus I really want to learn more about these, cohomology, Lie groups, Symplectic geometry, ... . But this question showed that there are a lot of gaps I have to fill. Your argument about orientability seems enough to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{RP}^3$ has mod-$2$ cohomology ring $\mathbb Z_2[x]/x^4$ while $\mathbb{RP}^2\times S^1$ has mod-$2$ cohomology ring $\mathbb Z_2[x]/x^2\otimes\mathbb Z_2[y]/y^2$. These two rings are non-isomorphic, so these spaces are not even homotopy equivalent.

---

Alternatively:

- just comparing $H^1(-,\mathbb Z_2)$ is enough.
- calculate fundamental groups. $\mathbb{RP}^3$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/2$, while $\mathbb{RP}^2\times S^1$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2$.

Answer (score 2):

The universal covering space of $\mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^3$ is $S^3$ and of $\mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1$ is $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$. $S^3 \ncong S^2\times\mathbb{R}$, since $S^3$ is compact and $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ not.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb P\mathbb R^2$ thus $\mathbb P\mathbb R^2\times S^1$  is not orientable, but $SO(3)$ certainly is as a Lie group.

The way you try to parametrize $SO(3)$ has a few problems.

- The identity element $I_3$ corresponds to infinitely many elements in $\mathbb P\mathbb R^2\times S^1$.
- An axis and an angle doesn't immediately produce an element in $SO(3)$: you need to know which direction to go. If instead of $\mathbb P\mathbb R^2$, we use $S^2$ to parametrize the axes, then we may go clockwise along the axis by convention but this won't give a one-to-one parametrization of $SO(3)$ but a covering space. We may try to associate a direction to go for each line instead of a direction vector, but this won't be consistent according to the non-orientability of $\mathbb P\mathbb R^2$.

So you can't consider $SO(3)$ as a fibre bundle over $\mathbb P\mathbb R^2$ as described. But there is a way to do it: embed the Lie group $S^1$ into $SO(3)$ through a fixed axis, and $SO(3)$ would be a $S^1$-principle bundle over the coset space. This should be related to the Hopf fibration of $S^3$, the universal cover of $SO(3)$.